# Picasso does not load bigger images from url

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, picasso

I load images from urls using Picasso. Image loading worked so far for every image until I tried it with an jpeg image that has higher size than others (1MB). I try to load the image using imageTarget that should not be garbage collected as it is declared as below:

```
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, displayImageUrl: String?) {
    val imageTarget: com.squareup.picasso.Target = object : com.squareup.picasso.Target {
    override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap, loadedFrom: Picasso.LoadedFrom) {
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }

    override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) 

    }

    override fun onPrepareLoad(drawable: Drawable?) {

    }
}
```

}

`onBitmapLoaded` is not executed, only `onPrepareLoad` is.
Picasso logs below say that target was garbage collected, but how is this possible if `onPrepareLoad` is executed. Does this message refer to the downloaded image that was cleaned from memory? The image is loaded using Picasso earlier for a list view that contains a thumbnail of the image and works fine as I can see the image on the list, but when I open the screen with the large view of the image it does not load it.

```
2022-03-25 10:03:41.462 8949-9021/mobile.debug D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R5]+2ms 
2022-03-25 10:03:41.463 8949-9023/mobile.debug D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R5]+3ms 
2022-03-25 10:03:42.386 8949-9023/mobile.debug D/Picasso: Hunter      decoded      [R5]+925ms 
2022-03-25 10:03:42.388 8949-9021/mobile.debug D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R5]+927ms for completion
2022-03-25 10:03:42.505 8949-8963/mobile.debug I/ge.mobile.debu: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 80414(6068KB) AllocSpace objects, 75(1628KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 14MB/28MB, paused 823us total 133.822ms
2022-03-25 10:03:42.523 8949-8949/mobile.debug D/Picasso: Main        canceled     [R5]+1062ms target got garbage collected
2022-03-25 10:03:42.631 8949-9021/mobile.debug D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R5]+1171ms 
2022-03-25 10:03:42.631 8949-8949/mobile.debug D/Picasso: Main        completed    [R5]+1171ms from DISK
```

The call for loading the image is simple `Picasso.get().load(displayImageUrl).into(imageTarget)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to use `Picasso.get().load(displayImageUrl)` instead of `Target`. There was no need for resizing the image. The question why the `Target` fails sometimes is still unanswered though.

Answer (score 1):

Picasso does load images greater than 1MB.

```
           Picasso.get().load(url)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.gradient_placeholder_horizontal) 
                        .into(image)
```

Don't use Target. It doesn't work properly sometimes. Especially in a recycler view.

To get Bitmap use. you can get size with it.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.get().load(url).get();
```

you can use this **resize** &  **onlyScaleDown()**. Only scaledown will only resize if it is greater than given value in resize

```
     Picasso.get().load(url)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.gradient_placeholder_horizontal)
                        .resize(476, 678)
                        .onlyScaleDown()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use resize to load exactly size:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).resize(width, height).into(imageView);
```

Comment: How would this resolve the problem that I described with loading only large images?

Comment: It will work, you can try

Comment: ok, but how would I then get the original size of the image loaded? As I don't want to make it smaller. Also, how would I then get the bitmap that was loaded into view?